# Username in current session

Tags: php, forms, symfony, session

I want to add hidden field with username in current session. Username is in another entity called User. How to solve it?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array('required' => false))
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array('style' => 'resize: none')))
        ->add('imageFile', FileType::class);
}



public function addPhotoAction(Request $request)
{
    $photo = new Photo();
    $user = $this->getUser()->getId();
    $form = $this->createForm(PhotoFormType::class, $photo);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($photo);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'You\'ve shared a photo!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }

    return $this->render('pages/addPhoto.html.twig', [
        'photoForm' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $user
    ]);
}
```

How can I add userId to $builder? id(user table) must be in addedBy(photo table). I have to do a relation?

Comment: Did you tried to get the user from the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push the data to the form field. If you add a hidden field to form object it looks like these rows.

```
$form = $this->createForm(PhotoFormType::class, $photo);
$form->get('usernameField')->setData($this->getUser()->getUsername());
```